# Typescript break points not working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I cannot set debug break points in typescript or JavaScript.  I have an ASP.Net Core application that uses an Angular 2 front end and a Web API back end.  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 RC  on Windows 10.  I am using Microsoft Edge browser and debugging in IIS Express.  The Web API debugging in C# is working as expected.  I have researched the issue and tried all the settings that I could find in VS 2017.

When I run the program (F5), I attach the debugger to the processes MicrosoftEdge.exe and MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe. In Options/Debugging/Symbols, I have checked “Microsoft Symbol Servers” and selected a temp folder for “cache symbols in this directory”.  For automatically load symbols for: I have selected “All modules, unless excluded”.  However, when I set the break point in typescript or javascript, the button is white and the hover text says “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document” and typescript break points do not stop the code.